# SharePoint Designer workflow Approval criteria

Tags: designer-workflow

I have created a SharePoint Designer workflow and at one step
 it should send an email to user if it is approved
 else      send an email to user if it is rejected.

so I gave a condition like "If Current Item: WorkflowStatus equal to 16
                               send an email to user
                              else if current Item: workflowstatus equal to 17
                               send an email to user"

the problem is the user is not getting any email even though the workflow is approved or rejected. please let me know why its not working. Is it due to SharePoint designer not recognizing workflow status codes (16 for approval and 17 for Rejection).

Answer (score 1):

It is not taking value you have specified for approval/rejection. It should be like :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the values you are trying to use are only applicable when Versioning is using Approval - that your list/library, because these are valid only withing the context when using the Approval workflow then the return codes for this, are defined in the ReviewRoutingState enumeration within the Microsoft.Office.Workflow namespace (Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Routing assembly), as follows 
Canceled = 15, Approved = 0×10 (16), Rejected = 0×11 (17)

If you are not in this situation, i believe it doesn't even  go through that.

I'm also wondering why didn't you use simply the Approval status of the List Item, as the Approval Workflows can change that for you.

Comment: Marius, I am using the Approval Status field from the List but still Its not sending an email to user

Comment: Tried writing to the Log for trial?